# How can I access a row by its index using pandas itertuples() methode?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my code where I need to access a certain tuple from the DataFrame df. Can you please help me with this matter as I can't find any answer regarding this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
    df_sheet_index = pd.read_excel("path/to/excel/file.xlsx")
    df = df_sheet_index.itertuples()
    for tuple in df:
        print(tuple)
```

This is the output

```
Pandas(Index=0, _1=nan, _2=nan, _3=nan, _4=nan, _5=nan, _6=nan, _7=nan, _8=nan, _9=nan, _10=nan, _11=nan, _12=nan, _13=nan, _14=nan, _15=nan, _16=nan, _17=nan, _18=nan, _19=nan, _20=nan, _21=nan, _22=nan)
Pandas(Index=1, _1=nan, _2=nan, _3=nan, _4=nan, _5=nan, _6=nan, _7=nan, _8=nan, _9=nan, _10=nan, _11=nan, _12=nan, _13=nan, _14=nan, _15=nan, _16=nan, _17=nan, _18=nan, _19=nan, _20=nan, _21=nan, _22=nan)
Pandas(Index=2, _1=nan, _2=nan, _3=nan, _4=nan, _5=nan, _6=nan, _7=nan, _8=nan, _9=nan, _10=nan, _11=nan, _12=nan, _13=nan, _14=nan, _15=nan, _16=nan, _17=nan, _18=nan, _19=nan, _20=nan, _21=nan, _22=nan)
...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's likely an easier and more efficient way

Comment: What do you want? Find rows that match a specific value?

Comment: As I said I am trying to print a tuple by providing its index

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: As a general rule, you should use pandas builtin functions to search inside and not iterate on it. It's more efficient and more readable.
But if you really want to access the tuples:

```py
target_index= 10
for tu in df.itertuples():
    if tu[0] == target_index:
        print(tu)
```

in a more general view, this is a regular tuple so you can access each element by its position. index will be tuple[0] then you first column tuple[1], the second tuple[2] etc.

***NOTE***: do not use `tuple` as a variable name, this is a reserved name in Python for the tuple type and it may create issue (on top of not being a good practice)

Comment: thank you for your fast reponse. I have editted the code. what i am trying to do is access a tuple by providing its index but I can quite figure out how to do it. I want to iterate over these tuples by providing the index you see in the beginning of the tuple

Comment: I still think you should use the DataFrame and not the tuples as it is quite difficult to work with. But if this is what you want, you can access the tuple index by tuple[0] and make a if statement on that. See my updated answer

Comment: thank you so much i think this would help. I will try to apply this to my code and tell you

Answer (score 0):

if u are trying to  get an element at a specific place. U can use .iloc()
It takes two pars the row & column

```
df.iloc[-1]["column"]
```

This will get the last row element at that column
For df.loc["row","column"]
df.loc[[]] returns a df while df.loc[] returns a series

Comment: thank you for your reply but that's not what i am trying to do